# First Time Making A hangman game

Tags: python, hangman

I've Never really made a game or such in python but was bored, so I tried to make a hangman game. I don't like how many if else statements I used but I can’t think of a better way to do it. Any feedback is appreciated!

```py
# global varibles
SECRET_WORD = "Python".lower()

#main function
def main():
    #setups Variable
    CHAR_WORD = set(SECRET_WORD)
    NUMBER_OF_GUESSES = 6
    CORRECT_GUESSES = set()
    WRONG_GUESSES = set()

    # while we still have guess
    while NUMBER_OF_GUESSES > 0:

        # gets our next guess
        current_guess = input("Guess: ").lower()

        # checks if our guess is only 1 char long
        if len(current_guess) != 1:
            print("Please Input a Character")
        
        # checks if we have already guessed the character
        elif current_guess in CORRECT_GUESSES or current_guess in WRONG_GUESSES:
            print("Already Guess that Character")

        else:
            #if our guess is in the word we add the the char to the correct guesses set
            if current_guess in CHAR_WORD:
                CORRECT_GUESSES.add(current_guess)
                print(f"Correct, {NUMBER_OF_GUESSES} guesses remaining. Current Word: {blank_letters(CORRECT_GUESSES, SECRET_WORD)}\n")

            else:
                WRONG_GUESSES.add(current_guess)
                NUMBER_OF_GUESSES -= 1
                print(f"Wrong, {NUMBER_OF_GUESSES} guesses remaining. Current Word: {blank_letters(CORRECT_GUESSES, SECRET_WORD)}\n")
            
            if CORRECT_GUESSES == CHAR_WORD:
                break
    
    # if we break out of the loop and have more than 1 guess we win
    if NUMBER_OF_GUESSES != 0:
        print("Congratulations, You Won")
    #if we break out the loop and have 0 guess we have lost
    else:
        print(f"You Lost, The Word Was: {SECRET_WORD}")

#used to return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed
def blank_letters(current_Guesses, secret_Word):
    return_sting = ""

    #loops through all the letters 
    for i in range(len(secret_Word)):
        # if we havent guess the current letter we replace that letter with an underscore
        if secret_Word[i] not in current_Guesses:
            return_sting += '_'
        
        # if we have guessed the current word we replace it with that letter
        else:
            return_sting += secret_Word[i]
        
    return return_sting

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("\n")
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

I have split up my suggestions into various sections. Overall the code was pretty well formatted, there were some small syntax changes I would recommend as well as a bit of potential restructuring of your code.

### Function Docstrings & declarations

For your `blank_letters()` function you put the docstring as a single line comment above the function. While this is mostly fine when someone is looking directly at your source code in a small program, it is better to use a properly formatted docstring to explain your functions like [numpystyle](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard) or [google style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#38-comments-and-docstrings).

Personally I prefer numpystyle docstrings that have the parameter and returns section, along with a short description. For something small like this where you **know** what types you are going to use I also recommend using [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), but this is more personal preference.

So instead of:

```py
#used to return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed
def blank_letters(current_Guesses, secret_Word):
    return_sting = ""

    #loops through all the letters 
    for i in range(len(secret_Word)):
        # if we havent guess the current letter we replace that letter with an underscore
        if secret_Word[i] not in current_Guesses:
            return_sting += '_'
        
        # if we have guessed the current word we replace it with that letter
        else:
            return_sting += secret_Word[i]
        
    return return_sting
```

You could do

```py
def blank_letters(current_Guesses:set, secret_Word:str) -> str:
    """Used to return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed

    Parameters
    ----------
    current_Guesses : set
        The set of characters the player has guessed

    secret_Word : str
        The word they are trying to guess

    Returns
    -------
    str
        A printable string that displays where guessed characters appear in word
    """
    return_sting = ""

    #loops through all the letters 
    for i in range(len(secret_Word)):
        # if we havent guess the current letter we replace that letter with an underscore
        if secret_Word[i] not in current_Guesses:
            return_sting += '_'
        
        # if we have guessed the current word we replace it with that letter
        else:
            return_sting += secret_Word[i]
        
    return return_sting
```

In VSCode and other tools these style of docstrings also give you helpful hints when trying to run functions and remember parameters. If you also use VSCode there is [an extension to autogenerate these](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring) and similar functionality exists in pycharm etc.:
[image: example vs code]

### Naming conventions and readability

Overall the readability was pretty good. The only thing that was a little awkward was the `CHAR_WORD` variable. There are two ways to adress this, the first is to put a little note next to where you are defining the variables:

```py
#main function
def main():
    # Setup Variables

    CHAR_WORD = set(SECRET_WORD) # Set of characters in SECRET_WORD
    NUMBER_OF_GUESSES = 6        # How many guesses the player gets
    CORRECT_GUESSES = set()      # Set of characters player guessed that are in the SECRET_WORD
    WRONG_GUESSES = set()        # Set of characters player guessed that are not in the SECRET_WORD

    ... # Rest of code
```

The second would be to maybe rename this to something more obvious like `ANSWER_CHARACTERS`. This just helps convey to people what the variable is for, since at first it took me a little bit of tracing to figure it out.

Oh, also change `current_Guesses` in `blank_letters()` to `current_guesses`, so it matches the correct syntax along with everything else.

### Restructuring/Refactoring

Since this is a single game you can take this next part with a grain of salt, since it's more preference than hard/fast rule. I personally try to make any projects I have work in two ways:

1. When people just run the file
2. When people import my project into their own project

Since this is a game it may seem pointless to let people import it, but I personally built a mini command-line launcher for a bunch of my games I wrote a few years ago and being able to easily import that code saved me a bunch of time and it gets you practice for when you have projects that benefit from it more.

In your case the easiest and fastest way to just get this up and running would be to add an optional keyword parameter to your `main()` function that allows people to specify the word (which gets rid of the global variable), and add a docstring to it. So something like this:

```py
def main(SECRET_WORD:str = "python"):
    """Primary function that runs whole hangman game

    Parameters
    ----------
    SECRET_WORD : str, optional
        The word players need to guess, by default "python"
    """
    ... # Function code
```

This means if you ever want to use your game in another project you can just do:

```py
from hangman import main # assuming your file is called `hangman.py`

SECRET_WORD = "" # Put word here

main(SECRET_WORD)
```

You could take this further by refactoring the game into a custom `Game` class instead, or splitting up the main loop into multiple functions instead of just 1 main function but I think that would be a bit overkill for a sub-80 line project.

Answer (score 2):

## PEP 8

The [Style Guide for Python Code (PEP8)](https://pep8.org/) enumerates many conventions which should be followed to increase readability of the code.  Please read it.

PEP 8 states that variable names and function names should be in `snake_case`.  `CAP_WORDS` are only for constants. `CHAR_WORD`, `CORRECT_GUESSES`, `WRONG_GUESSES`, and `NUMBER_OF_GUESSES` are variables, so should be in `snake_case`.  Additionally, `secret_Word` and `current_Guesses` should not have uppercase letters.

## Naming

`return_sting` should probably be `return_string`.

`main()` is an obvious name for the main function, but it doesn't really convey any information.  It would be better to name the function something like `hangman_game()`.

## Global variables

Global variables are, in general, a bad idea.  Avoid them when possible.

You have one, which is used exactly once: passing `SECRET_WORD` into `main()`.  You understand parameters, as you could have used the global variable in `blank_letters()`, but instead choose to pass `SECRET_WORD` into `blank_letters()` as a parameter.  Simply reuse this pattern:

```py
def hangman_game(secret_word: str) -> None:
    ... omitted ...

def main() -> None:
    secret_word = "Python".lower()
    print("\n")
    hangman_game(secret_word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here, I've used `main()` to hide the main script's variables inside the `main()` function scope, preventing them from accidentally becoming global variables.

## lowercase

The game loop calls `input("Guess: ").lower()` to turn anything the user types in into lowercase.  Clearly, the secret word has to be given in lower case.  That is performed by the global script, and now in the `main()` code.  However, if the game is given a secret word with uppercase characters, it should change that to lowercase, instead of relying on the caller properly providing a lowercase secret word:

```py
def hangman_game(secret_word: str) -> None:
    secret_word = secret_word.lower()
    ... omitted ...

def main() -> None:
    print("\n")
    hangman_game("Python")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Loop like a native

(Section title from [talk by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html))

The loop:

```py
for i in range(len(secret_Word)):
    ... never use "i" except in "secret_Word[i]" ...
```

is an anti-pattern.  Python is a scripting language, which (indirectly) means it can be very inefficient.  In your case, you are actually making it worse!  Here, you are determining the length of a container, and then looping over the range of indices into that container.  For each index, you then retrieve the value of in the container at that index.  If a test fails (`secret_Word[i] not in current_Guesses`), you then are repeating the retrieval of the value of the container at that index (`return_sting += secret_Word[i]`).

The Python designers know that iterating over containers can be inefficient, so they have given us tools to do it efficiently.

```py
for letter in secret_Word:
    ... use letter ...
```

The indexing is now done internally by Python.  It is done exactly once per element, with the value stored in `letter`, which can be reused many times inside the loop without having to reindex into the container.

Improved code (version 1):

```py
def blank_letters(current_guesses: set[str], secret_word: str) -> str:
    """return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed"""

    return_string = ""

    #loops through all the letters 
    for letter in secret_word:
        # if we haven't guessed the current letter, replace that letter with an underscore
        if letter not in current_guesses:
            return_string += '_'
        
        # if we have guessed the current letter, append it unchanged
        else:
            return_string += letter
        
    return return_string
```

Note.  If you are on Python 3.8 or earlier, you'll need to replace the type hint `set[str]` with `Set[str]`, and add `from typing import Set` at the top of the script.

The above code is better, but we can still improve it.  It has a common pattern.  Initialize an accumulator, loop through a container, for each item, add something to the accumulator.  Python has built-in syntax to support things like this.  One is the `... if ... else ...` ***expression*** (not the `if ... elif ... else ...` statement):

Improved code (version 2):

```py
def blank_letters(current_guesses: set[str], secret_word: str) -> str:
    """return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed"""

    return_string = ""

    #loops through all the letters 
    for letter in secret_word:
        # if we haven't guessed the current letter, replace that letter with an underscore
        return_string += letter if letter in current_guesses else '_'
        
    return return_string
```

Now we are accumulating `letter` or `'_'` into `return_string`.  So we have the structure:

```py
    accumulator = ""
    for thing in container:
        accumulator += expression
```

This structure is easily replaced with a string join on a generator expression: `"".join(expression for thing in container)`.

Improved code (version 3):

```py
def blank_letters(current_guesses: set[str], secret_word: str) -> str:
    """return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed"""

    # Replace unguessed letters with an underscore.
    return "".join(letter if letter in current_guesses else '_' for letter in secret_word)
```

I've replaced your function 7 statement function with a 1 statement function.  This might cause you some worry ... so let's make sure it works.

Improved code (version 4):

```py
def blank_letters(current_guesses: set[str], secret_word: str) -> str:
    """
    Return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed

    >>> blank_letters(set(), "hello")
    '_____'

    >>> blank_letters({'l', 'e'}, "hello")
    '_ell_'

    >>> blank_letters({'h', 'o', 'x', 'y', 'z'}, "hello")
    'h___o'
    """

    # Replace unguessed letters with an underscore.
    return "".join(letter if letter in current_guesses else '_' for letter in secret_word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Now I've added "doctest" code into the docstring for the function.  `doctest.testmod()` will read the docstrings for the functions inside the file, look for the lines which start with `>>>`, and execute the code on that line.  If the returned values matches the following text, the test passes.

For example, if you change the last test to use `"Hello"` instead of "`hello"`, and run the code, you'd see something like:

```
**********************************************************************
File "C:/Users/aneufeld/Documents/Stack Exchange/Code Review/hangman.py", line 11, in __main__.blank_letters
Failed example:
    blank_letters({'h', 'o', 'x', 'y', 'z'}, "Hello")
Expected:
    'h___o'
Got:
    '____o'
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   3 in __main__.blank_letters
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
>>>
```

## State variables

You maintain two sets: `CORRECT_GUESSES` and `WRONG_GUESSES`.  `WRONG_GUESSES` is only used to validate the letter hasn't been guessed before:

```py
        elif current_guess in CORRECT_GUESSES or current_guess in WRONG_GUESSES:
            print("Already Guess that Character")
```

Consider instead simply maintaining a `GUESSES` variable.  If each new guess (right or wrong) is added to `GUESSES`, then the above test simplifies to:

```py
        elif current_guess in GUESSES:
            print("Already Guess that Character")
```

Note that, as shown in the doctest for `blank_letters`, including both incorrect guesses along with correct guesses still results in the correctly blanked secret word, you could even pass `GUESSES` instead of `CORRECT_GUESSES` to the function:

```py
                print(f"... Current Word: {blank_letters(GUESSES, SECRET_WORD)}\n")
```

With that change, the only place `CORRECT_GUESSES` is used is testing if all of the letters in `CHAR_WORD` have been guessed.  Python has a rich set of set comparison operations, so this:

```py
            if CORRECT_GUESSES == CHAR_WORD:
                break
```

could be replaced with:

```py
            if GUESSES >= CHAR_WORD:
                break
```

and we've eliminated the `CORRECT_GUESSES` variable as well.

## Improved Code

```py
def hangman_game(secret_word: str, max_guesses: int = 6) -> None:
    """A console-based hangman game"""

    secret_word = secret_word.lower()
    
    correct_letters = set(secret_word)
    guesses_left = max_guesses
    guesses = set()

    while guesses_left:

        current_guess = input("Guess: ").lower()

        if len(current_guess) != 1:
            print("Please Input a Character")
        
        elif current_guess in guesses:
            print("Already Guessed that Character")

        else:
            guesses.add(current_guess)
            if current_guess in correct_letters:
                print(f"Correct, ", end='')

            else:
                guesses_left -= 1
                print(f"Wrong, ", end='')
    
            print(f"{guesses_left} guesses remaining. Current Word: {blank_letters(guesses, secret_word)}\n")
            
            if guesses >= correct_letters:
                break
    
    if guesses_left:
        print("Congratulations, You Won")
    else:
        print(f"You Lost, The Word Was: {secret_word}")

def blank_letters(current_guesses: set[str], secret_word: str) -> str:
    """
    Return a string only showing the letters we have already guessed

    >>> blank_letters(set(), "hello")
    '_____'

    >>> blank_letters({'l', 'e'}, "hello")
    '_ell_'

    >>> blank_letters({'h', 'o', 'x', 'y', 'z'}, "hello")
    'h___o'
    """

    # Replace unguessed letters with an underscore.
    return "".join(letter if letter in current_guesses else '_' for letter in secret_word)

def main():
    print("\n")
    hangman_game("Python")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    main()
```